# Heavy load because of concurrent users causes 502 bad gateway error

Tags: php, nginx

I have Nginx + PHP FPM installed on my server. We are putting load on server for long period for 30 concurrent users.

For initial user it works fine but after some time it starts throwing 502 bad gateway error.

I have placed some of the log of nginx php-fpm and slow log of php-fpm.

There are entries getting logged in slow log of php-fpm because of long running script and load on server. I think this is the reason for 502 bad gateway error. But I dont know how to solve that problem.

- What are the tweaks I need to make in php-fpm.conf so that this errors gets resolved?
- How to make nginx wait for long time for response from php-fpm?
- How to increase php-fpm max execution time?

Here are the logs attached.

#### NGINX LOG

> 2013/01/29 15:03:38 [error] 2493#0: *1046562 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 49.248.0.2, server:* ******.com, request: "GET MY_SCRIPT_URI HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "***********.com", referrer: "MY_SCRIPT_URL"
>
> 2013/01/29 15:03:39 [error] 2493#0: *1046561 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 49.248.0.2, server:* *****.com, request: "GET MY_SCRIPT_URI HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "***********.com", referrer: "MY_SCRIPT_URL"

There are many errors of this type and they are repeating in entire file.

#### PHP FPM LOG

```
[14-Feb-2013 12:54:13] ERROR: failed to ptrace(PEEKDATA) pid 10748: Input/output error (5)
[14-Feb-2013 12:54:18] ERROR: failed to ptrace(PEEKDATA) pid 10112: Input/output error (5)
[14-Feb-2013 12:54:18] ERROR: failed to ptrace(PEEKDATA) pid 12147: Input/output error (5)
[14-Feb-2013 12:54:19] ERROR: failed to ptrace(PEEKDATA) pid 30857: Input/output error (5)
[snip: many more]
```

#### PHP FPM SLOW LOG

> [14-Feb-2013 12:55:13] [pool www] pid 10748
>   script_filename = MY_SCRIPT_PATH
>   [0x00007f446e8e06b0] curl_exec() MY_SCRIPT_PATH_1.php:317
>   [0x00007f446e8e0490] callService() MY_SCRIPT_PATH_2:1331
>   [0x00007f446e8e0148] convertToPurchaseOrders() MY_SCRIPT_PATH_3:15
>   [0x00007fff0102b4d0] convertToPurchaseOrders() unknown:0
>   [0x00007f446e8de0d8] call_user_func_array() MY_SCRIPT_PATH_4:359
>   [0x00007f446e8dd4d0] +++ dump failed
>
> [14-Feb-2013 12:55:13] [pool www] pid 10117
>   script_filename = MY_SCRIPT_PATH
>   [0x00007f446e8e06b0] curl_exec() MY_SCRIPT_PATH_1.php:317
>   [0x00007f446e8e0490] callService() MY_SCRIPT_PATH_2:1331
>   [0x00007f446e8e0148] convert() MY_SCRIPT_PATH_3:15
>   [0x00007fff0102b4d0] convert() unknown:0
>   [0x00007f446e8de0d8] call_user_func_array() MY_SCRIPT_PATH_4:359
>   [0x00007f446e8dd4d0] +++ dump failed

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, 30 concurrent users is a fairly low load - depending on the application and the hardware, I'd be expecting significantly more.

Reading the slowlog, it looks like your application is invoking a curl_exec() command, and that this command is slow. What I'm guessing is happening is that your 30 concurrent users are all requesting your script; your script, in turn, is calling another web application somewhere, which is either very slow in responding, or timing out altogether (based on `max_execution_time` in php.ini). I don't know the ins and outs of NGINX and PHP-FPM, but I assume that there's a maximum number of concurrent PHP instances it fires up; as those instances are all tied up waiting for your CURL request to return, NGINX is unable to fire up any more instances of PHP, and returns a bad gateway instead.

The first thing I'd look at is speeding up the response time of your script, either by running the CURL request asynchronously, or caching it, or finding another way of speeding it up - running a synchronous CURL request basically means the performance and scalability of your site depends completely on the performance and scalability of the URL you're calling.

If you can't do that, reduce the timeout for CURL (max_execution_time in php.ini) to 5 seconds; this will cause some of your CURL requests to fail, but at least your app can handle that and return more quickly to the user; it also means you have far fewer PHP threads waiting around.

There is, presumably, a way of increasing the number of PHP instances NGINX fires up; you can play with that, but you're only moving the problem marginally - no web server can support lots of waiting threads gracefully.

Comment: Hi. The curl web service I am calling it our service only but written in different technology. And the service being call takes long time because its complex processing happening and it needs to be synchronous because its transactional system. Somehow I need way so that my Nginx dont throw 502 bad gateway even though there are some request waiting. I want to increase time for what nginx should wait.

Comment: You can increase the number of processes PHP FPM spawns by changing the config file - but you will only move the problem. The reason there's a limit on the number of processes is because there's a limit to server resources, and once you consume them all, the results are unpredictable. The default configuration values are usually fairly conservative - so you might be able to move them upwards without ill effect. However, you can't move them upwards endlessly.
Your application will not scale if you have to wait for long-running, synchronous processes.